# spring mvc @RequestPart validation via annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, multipartform-data, hibernate-validator

How can I validate that the *body request part* is not empty?

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun createMessage(@Valid @RequestPart message: MessageCreate,
                  @Valid @RequestPart @NotEmpty body: MultipartFile,
                  @RequestParam attachments: List<MultipartFile>) {
    return service.create(message, body, attachments)
}
```

I tried to create a custom validator annotation that checks body.isEmpty() result but it has no effect. What is missing ? Is it possible do to it this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@NotNull` before the request body object.

Refer this for more info : [Null request body not getting caught by Spring @RequestBody @Valid annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301070/null-request-body-not-getting-caught-by-spring-requestbody-valid-annotations)

Comment: @NotNull checks if body param is null. I'd like to check the result of body.isEmpty(). But it does not check anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/messages")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun createMessage(@Valid @RequestPart message: MessageCreate,
                  @Valid @RequestPart @NotEmpty body: MultipartFile,
                  result: BindingResult,
                  @RequestParam attachments: List<MultipartFile>) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //handle validation failure
    }

    return service.create(message, body, attachments)
}
```

Note: `BindingResult` argument must be declared immediately after the validated method argument.